# read content of base64 encoded certificate

Tags: ssl, openssl, base64, certificate

I am having some troubles reading a base64 encoded SSL certificate. What I have is a base64 encoded string without "----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----" and "----END CERTIFICATE----". I am trying to read it with multiple ways but it failed to me

I tried to read the cert via cmd

```
openssl x509 -in cdg_cert -text -noout
```

and getting `:PEM routines:CRYPTO_internal:no start Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE error`

I also tried to decode the string and save it on my disk which ends up with a binary file and still couldn't read it via openssl cmd which ends up with same error

Googling around and haven't found any good hints, can anyone please help me on the cmd I should use? I am running a macbook and trying to read the cert content

Comment: *"I am trying to read it with multiple ways but it failed to me"* - which says absolutely nothing on what you really did. If it is just missing the PEM header and footer (i.e. `----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----` ...) the obvious thing would be to add these - but you don't describe anything like this. Apart from there you only describe what is obviously not there, but you don't describe sufficiently what is there (only that there is something base64 encoded - but what exactly?). This means there is __no way to know what you actually have__ and thus no way to find out how to use it properly.

Comment: Yes sorry missed those info. I tried add the header but still not working and it says invalid cert.

Comment: *"... still not working and it says invalid cert."* - still lack of sufficient details and nothing to reproduce here for others. This is like asking a mechanic what's wrong with your car without given the mechanic a chance to see the car and without describing any details apart from "does not work". And the information "base64" is equivalent to "the car is red", i.e. provides some information but these are not that much useful without having more information.

Comment: Hi @SteffenUllrich thank you for your reply. Basically what I am trying to do is, I got a base64 encoded string and was told it's a PEM key. Unfortunately that the guy who upload this base64 encoded string is no longer working with us. So the string is saved in a secret service and now I've saved it in my machine. I am trying to read this as a PEM but don't know how to start. I tried to decode it to a file (which saved as a binary file), and try to read it by the cmd I posted above but didn't work. Here's no header / footer in the base 64 string, any hints how should I start?

Comment: The b64 encoded string is a one liner without \n or line breaks, and I am trying to understand that how do I handle this string and process it as PEM

Comment: PEM data have a header and footer so the information that it is PEM was obviously wrong. I can simply take a PEM encoded certificate, remove header and footer to have only the base64 and later add it back and it will work. So if this does not work in your case it was likely not a PEM encoded certificate with just header and footer removed. But what it really is - who knows since you don't let others see what you have. You might try to base64 decode it and then try to use [asn1parse](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-asn1parse.html) to check if it is even ASN.1 what's inside.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue

```
unable to load certificate
459600:error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:../openssl-1.1.1a/crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:745:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
```

, and after struggling a lot, just trying to use a text editor and wrapped the header/footer around the base64 encoded part:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...(cert content goes here)...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Afterwards, I was able to read the cert using:

```
"c:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\openssl" x509 -text -noout  -in IdP_Signing_Certificate.crt
```

As already mentioned in comments, you should know which header you need to place, as it's part of the PEM definition. The Strings within the header are defined here, and depend on the content provided in the cert, which is the unknown piece added to PEM:

https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/include/openssl/pem.h

In short: **PEM is just the base64 DER output + header/footer**.